# TeXstudio doesn't display errors on compilation but freezes!

Tags: compiling, texstudio

I am on TeXstudio 2.11 on OS X El Capitan and using a [class file](http://journals.cambridge.org/data/relatedlink/JFMIFCs19_04_2016.zip) provided by a journal to typeset a paper. With this class file, I can happily compile and produce my document in TeXstudio if there are no errors. However, if  there are any syntax errors, TeXstudio just freezes (displaying a circular cursor) and does not show me what the errors are. A minimal example of the code that freezes is shown below:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\sin %this line has an error, which just freezes the compiler! 
\end{document}
```

I tried compiling the same latex file with TeXshop and it  displays the error. So I am inclined to believe that this is not due to the class file or my latex document, but something to do with TeXstudio itself. However, TeXstudio is able to pop out errors with some other latex files that I compile.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. I'm inclined to believe your right about what you conjecture. I doubt though that anyone will be able to make a much stronger statement without gettin gmore details on what you are compiling and which system you have in place. Try to take the document causing these problems, remove part one by one until you find the minimal example that still has the error you're talking about. Maybe if you post this plus some details on your system people will be able to help

Comment: Very weird indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with this class `\documentclass{jfm}`. Remove that and instead use `\documentclass{article}`. This should work. I had the same problem and after too many hours of struggling, found out about it. After you are done with your article and debugged all errors you can include the `jfm` class before submission. I hope this can help.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what in that file causes the bug

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with jfm style. With this class file TeXstudio hangs on any error during compilation. I recommend to open a terminal window and run pdflatex from the command line:

> pdflatex YourFile.tex

Then you could see the errors; after correction TeXstudio compiles the file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/240046)